# SweetAlert Javascript plugin preventing Capybara from continuing to next page during tests

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist, sweetalert

I am in the process of adding [sweetalert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert) to a page so that if a customer forgot to upload files, it would warm them with sweetalert when they clicked on the continue button before continuing to the next page.

button html:

```
<a href="/checkout/address" class="checkout-now continue-to-checkout">Checkout Now &gt;</a>
```

click handler javascript:

```
$(HtmlIds.cart.checkoutBtn).click(function(e) {
            if ($(HtmlIds.cart.missingUploadsTag).length !== 0) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
              SweetAlert({
                title: "Missing Uploads",
                text: "Your print job(s) are missing file uploads, which will cause a delay in the production of your order. " +
                  "To upload a file to a print job, please click on the 'Update Files' links in your shopping cart.",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "I understand, proceed anyway"
              }, function(isConfirm) {
                  if (isConfirm)
                    window.location.href = linkURL;
              });
            }
          });
```

The code works fine. However, i am having a problem with testing via rspec and capybara. When i try to proceed to get to the next page, the test fails and capybara/poltergeist errors out when i check to see if im on the next page.

rspec/capybara test code:

```
click_link "Checkout Now"
find(".sweet-alert").should have_content("Missing Uploads") #wait until sweet alert pops up
click_button "I understand, proceed anyway"
#page.execute_script('$(".confirm").click()')
page.should have_content("Checkout: Delivery")
```

error message:

```
2) checkout should be able to go through checkout via shipping
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content("Checkout: Delivery")
       expected #has_content?("Checkout: Delivery") to return true, got false
```

Capybara seems to register the click when i use click_button because it doesn't error out saying the button doesn't exist, but it never continues to the next page. The forced jquery code thats commented out doesnt work either. If i remove the sweetalert from my code (and the click in my test) so the user continues no matter what the test passes.

Comment: What happens if you add a 'sleep 10' before the have_content expectation.  Does it pass then?

Comment: @Phil I just tried that. Still failing at 'page.should have_content("Checkout: Delivery")'

Comment: Just a guess: maybe `$(HtmlIds.cart.missingUploadsTag).length` is zero? That would prevent the SweetAlert code from executing.

Comment: If the sweet alert code didnt execute because the conditional failed, then nothing would happen in the .click() and the href would continue to /checkout/address. This would cause the 'find(".sweet-alert").should have_content("Missing Uploads")' to fail. As a sanity check, per your suggestion, i removed the conditional, and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Does the "I understand, proceed anyway" button have its own HTML that you can share with us?  Maybe you can use a different finder on it to make sure that the click is working properly.  Perhaps you need to click on a div or something instead.  I would be careful to assume that your click succeeded just because click_button did not error out.

Comment: I will update the html when i get back to work. If you look at the commented line below the click, i actually tried to force click the button. The button has a "confirm" class and i used jquery to force click it. That still did not work.

Comment: @Zyren: Did you solve this problem? I think I'm having the same problem. I can't click the default `OK` button (didn't modify it like it yours)

Comment: the problem was that poltergeist has an unsolved bug where using click or click_button isnt consistent when elements are undergoing transitions (fading in/out, etc). if you use .trigger("click") it works, but is not ideal. heres a reference of the bug on github:

https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using poltergeist, use .trigger("click") instead of click or click_button. There is a bug in poltergeist where click and click_button does not give consistent results (seems to be when elements are undergoing animations). 
[Poltergeist issue on github](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/530)